# Melody Notes With Borrowed Chords

Tags: chords, melody

If I got a chord progression and I borrow a chord from a parallel mode is the tension/harmony between the melody and the underlying chord to the parallel, or the original chord, or both?

Let's say I have the C Major scale. And I borrow from C Minor: ii* Ddim, can I then use Ab in theory? Or would I look in my melody then for notes which are in the original scale of C Major and harmonise with the borrowed chord. Or ideally which would harmonise with ii of C Major and ii* of C Minor?

EDIT: To clarify. The music genre I'm producing does not make much use of chords, and usually not in the context with a melody playing. I want to create a chord progression as a guidance, to play a melody over it and then remove it.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean, but the concept of a "borrowed" chord seems quite restrictive to me. By saying "borrowed chords" you imply that you’re mostly based in diatonic harmony. This then implies that you shouln’t modulate. If you do not use diatonic harmony or if you use modulations on the other hand you can do **anything** you want.

Comment: @Lazy I'm not sure whether you're unfamiliar with the concept or are just challenging it. If the former, see [Wikipedia on borrowed chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord); often talked about as [modal mixture](https://viva.pressbooks.pub/openmusictheory/chapter/modal-mixture/). The point is that it's not a whole *modulation* into a different mode, just "mixing" them both up a bit.

Comment: @AndyBonner Which kind of supports the point that if you work under the restriction of "borrowed chords" modulations should not be used, I think.

Comment: There are some sentences I don't understand in the question: *is the tension/harmony between the melody and the underlying chord to the parallel, or the original chord, or both?* What do we mean by "tension to"? The whole question seems to imply that modal mixture often involves some kind of clash between melody notes and the chords that harmonize them; this doesn't have to be the case. It's not clear to me whether you're asking about how to harmonize a melody, or to write a melody over a chord progression. And by "Ab," do you mean a pitch, or the chord A flat major?

Comment: @Lazy I mean if I use any chord which does not exist in this mode e.g. Major but in another mode e.g. Minor. Or if would be in another mode lets say Phrygian I use a chord from Locrian.

Comment: @Andy with tension I mean the opposite to harmony. Something which is not harmonic and creates tension. Let's say I have a chord C – Eb – G then I would consider a C in the melody as harmonic, and a C# as a lot of tension. 

To get back to the example the ii chord in C Major is D - F - A, and ii* of C Minor is D - F - Ab. I know that I can easily use D,F as it is in the C Major scale, in both chords, but what about Ab. It should harmonize with ii* but do I need to see it in the bigger context of the original mode.

Comment: 1) Remember that if you clarify by giving comments, the original question has not been changed. Please use the "edit" button below the question to make it clear. 2) Just a tip, the word "harmony" is used in some other ways than the meaning you just gave. The official music-theory way of talking about these ideas is "non-chordal tones," to describe melody notes that are not one of the pitches that make up the chord, vs "chordal tones." We also talk about "consonance" and "dissonance" to describe notes that "blend well" or create "tension." But note, some chords *contain* dissonance.

Comment: And it's *still* unclear to me whether this question is about how to create a melody over chords, or how to put chords under a melody. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: You say that "The music genre I'm producing does not make much use of chords, and usually not in the context with a melody playing" - writing a melody over a chord progression may be the wrong approach for this genre, period. (For example, instructions for how to write a fugue or other polyphonal work typically involve writing more than one melody and making sure they interact correctly and the voice leading is fine, not worrying about a chord progression at any point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I wouldn't worry about which scales to use when assigning melody notes to a borrowed chord: I just use a chord tone or two (or three!) and problem solved.

For example, you can definitely use D, F, and/or A♭ when assigning melody notes to a ii°-of-C minor chord in a C major piece. ...Or an F minor piece.

This still applies even if you're using even more exotic chords than easily borrowed ones (e.g. V of V, the Neapolitan or ♭II chord, the ♯IV chord, that tense A♭7 chord alternated with C minor chords in the Toad's Factory theme of *Mario Kart Wii*).

With the more conservative borrowed chords, most of the chord tones are still in the home key (e.g. the D and F in the first example are also in C major as well as C minor), so there's no need to worry about those.

If you do feel like using non-chord tones when assigning melody notes to your borrowed or more exotic chords, I'd play those by ear and test them out before settling down on them. While picking non-chord tones exclusively from the home key is likely a safer option, picking non-chord tones from any different keys the borrowed or exotic chord implies (e.g. picking C flat when soloing over or assigning melody to a G flat major chord in an F minor excerpt) can imply stronger modulation or tonicization and add more spice.

Answer (score 1):

A scale that fits comes from the underlying chord. So if you play Ddim chord (or Dø), then Ab note will be diatonic. Moreover, it will be a chord tone. It will sound "right", it will match. If you played A instead, it would sound off-key.

For various reasons you don't always need to play diatonic or chord notes. A common example is using notes from the upcoming chord to prepare for the change. Other examples are alterations and chromatic embellishments. But in general, if you change the harmony (by borrowing a chord) you typically want to emphasize that new chord by playing the chord tones.

With the scale tones other than the chord tones the situation is not so obvious. For example, a typically advised "first choice" scale for Dø is locrian scale, that would include Eb. It will likely sound right, and it will help to emphasize harmony change. But on the other hand you may consider playing locrian ♮2 with E, which would provide a smoother connection with other chords from the key of C major. Similarly you may want to try playing either Bb (from D locrian) or B (from C major).

But in the end if something sounds right to you, play it, and ask why it sounds good later.

Comment: "*So if you play Do chord (or Dø)*" —I read this as solfege, taking "Do" to mean C. But then I realized you're actually talking about D diminished and half diminished. You can use `<sup>o</sup>` to get a superscript, though maybe best to spell it out?

Comment: @AndyBonner Please I'd like to ask you to answer this question: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/diminished-and-half-diminished-chord-notation I realize there is some ambiguity in "Do" (although it should be obvious from the context), but I find superscript and subscript circles too small. Anyway, changing to Ddim.

Comment: Ok. I understood 1) Ab is more harmonic then A to ii* as it is contained in the chord. 2) The second pointI also understand that I will emphasize by including the new notes. 3) The last part I didn't get a 100%, do you mean if I have a chord progression, I would look for a scale on top which uses most of that notes. Also if I'm using Eb in C Locrian wouldn't this be ii chord and thus give another progression?

Comment: Another thing which I then don't understand here is, if my melody is harmonizing only with the underlying chord, then every note should be theoretically available in my melody, as I will always find a chord in another mode which contains those notes. Then the concept of a scale/modes becomes irrelevant for the melody, and is just important for the chords?

Comment: The question: "how to assign scale to a chord" is a material for at least a chapter in a book. If you're fixed on making modal interchange with C-minor, then scale using notes from C-minor, that it D-locrian, would be be the more natural. But often the procedure for finding a scale is: take the chord notes (typically 3, or 4, sometimes more), and then choose the remaining notes, and there are often several ways to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The 'scale of the key' is a framework, not a restriction.  Chromatic chords (and chromatic notes) are OK.  We don't have to justify them by 'borrowing'.

Yes, A♭ is very common in a piece in C major.   Maybe within a Fm chord, or a G7♭9 or a D♭7 substituting for a G7 dominant.   Being simply diatonic is good.  Being chromatic is also good, and doesn't have to be validated by being diatonic in some other key!

Comment: Borrowing is one way people get to chromatic progressions. There are many, many, many ways to write chromatic progressions you listed another which is substitutions. Instead of just saying Ab is common or being chromatic is also good, showing how it can be used will help this answer a lot.